# How to display picture and get mouse click coordinate on it

Tags: python, mouseevent, image

I am wondering if it is possible in Python (Windows) to show some picture, then click with the mouse on this picture and get the coordinates of this click relative to picture edges.

Thanks!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes it is possible and pretty easy once you understand tkinter, here's a quick script:

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
import Image, ImageTk

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()

    #setting up a tkinter canvas with scrollbars
    frame = Frame(root, bd=2, relief=SUNKEN)
    frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    xscroll = Scrollbar(frame, orient=HORIZONTAL)
    xscroll.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E+W)
    yscroll = Scrollbar(frame)
    yscroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)
    canvas = Canvas(frame, bd=0, xscrollcommand=xscroll.set, yscrollcommand=yscroll.set)
    canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)
    xscroll.config(command=canvas.xview)
    yscroll.config(command=canvas.yview)
    frame.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)

    #adding the image
    File = askopenfilename(parent=root, initialdir="C:/",title='Choose an image.')
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(File))
    canvas.create_image(0,0,image=img,anchor="nw")
    canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox(ALL))

    #function to be called when mouse is clicked
    def printcoords(event):
        #outputting x and y coords to console
        print (event.x,event.y)
    #mouseclick event
    canvas.bind("<Button 1>",printcoords)

    root.mainloop()
```

Unedited it will print using the default window coordinate system to the console. The canvas widget makes the top left corner the 0,0 point so you may have to mess around with the printcoords function. To get the loaded picture dimension you would use canvas.bbox(ALL), and you might want to switch to using canvasx and canvasy coords instead of how it is. If you're new to tkinter; google should be able to help you finish it from here :).

Comment: Shouldn't it be `from PIL import Image, ImageTk`

Comment: Imports in 3.7:
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL.Image import core as image
from PIL import ImageTk
from PIL import Image as PILImage

Answer (score 6):

Here's a version I had cobbled together a while ago using wxPython and various wxPython tutorials.  This prints the mouse click coordinates to a separate output window.  (Uses Python 2.6.2, wxPython 2.8.10.1)

Enter the path to your image in the `filepath` variable at the bottom.

```
import wx

class MyCanvas(wx.ScrolledWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent, id = -1, size = wx.DefaultSize, filepath = None):
        wx.ScrolledWindow.__init__(self, parent, id, (0, 0), size=size, style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)

        self.image = wx.Image(filepath)
        self.w = self.image.GetWidth()
        self.h = self.image.GetHeight()
        self.bmp = wx.BitmapFromImage(self.image)

        self.SetVirtualSize((self.w, self.h))
        self.SetScrollRate(20,20)
        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(0,0,0))

        self.buffer = wx.EmptyBitmap(self.w, self.h)
        dc = wx.BufferedDC(None, self.buffer)
        dc.SetBackground(wx.Brush(self.GetBackgroundColour()))
        dc.Clear()
        self.DoDrawing(dc)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.OnClick)

    def OnClick(self, event):
        pos = self.CalcUnscrolledPosition(event.GetPosition())
        print '%d, %d' %(pos.x, pos.y)

    def OnPaint(self, event):
        dc = wx.BufferedPaintDC(self, self.buffer, wx.BUFFER_VIRTUAL_AREA)

    def DoDrawing(self, dc):
        dc.DrawBitmap(self.bmp, 0, 0)

class MyFrame(wx.Frame): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None, id=-1, filepath = None): 
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title=filepath)
        self.canvas = MyCanvas(self, -1, filepath = filepath)

        self.canvas.SetMinSize((self.canvas.w, self.canvas.h))
        self.canvas.SetMaxSize((self.canvas.w, self.canvas.h))
        self.canvas.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(0, 0, 0))
        vert = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        horz = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        vert.Add(horz,0, wx.EXPAND,0)
        vert.Add(self.canvas,1,wx.EXPAND,0)
        self.SetSizer(vert)
        vert.Fit(self)
        self.Layout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    app.SetOutputWindowAttributes(title='stdout')  
    wx.InitAllImageHandlers()

    filepath = 'ENTER FILEPATH HERE'
    if filepath:
        print filepath
        myframe = MyFrame(filepath=filepath)
        myframe.Center()
        myframe.Show()
        app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I really like this! Is there some way to zoom in and out of the picture?

Answer (score 6):

Here's a revised version of bigjim's answer.  It works in python 3.4+ (didn't test anything else).  I didn't bother with the PIL part since tkinter's PhotoImage can handle gif and pgm which is enough to demo this.

The lambda function handles conversion between event (window) coordinates and image coordinates.

I also added support for press vs release since I had a need for that particular feature.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

event2canvas = lambda e, c: (c.canvasx(e.x), c.canvasy(e.y))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()

    #setting up a tkinter canvas with scrollbars
    frame = Frame(root, bd=2, relief=SUNKEN)
    frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    xscroll = Scrollbar(frame, orient=HORIZONTAL)
    xscroll.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E+W)
    yscroll = Scrollbar(frame)
    yscroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)
    canvas = Canvas(frame, bd=0, xscrollcommand=xscroll.set, yscrollcommand=yscroll.set)
    canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)
    xscroll.config(command=canvas.xview)
    yscroll.config(command=canvas.yview)
    frame.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)

    #adding the image
    File = askopenfilename(parent=root, initialdir="M:/",title='Choose an image.')
    print("opening %s" % File)
    img = PhotoImage(file=File)
    canvas.create_image(0,0,image=img,anchor="nw")
    canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox(ALL))

    #function to be called when mouse is clicked
    def printcoords(event):
        #outputting x and y coords to console
        cx, cy = event2canvas(event, canvas)
        print ("(%d, %d) / (%d, %d)" % (event.x,event.y,cx,cy))
    #mouseclick event
    canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>",printcoords)
    canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>",printcoords)

    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Tkinter to do this and its built in to python already.

http://www.pythonware.com/library/tkinter/introduction/

Answer (score 1):

A good alternative to Tkinter is using QT in Python. You can achieve that with [PyQT](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro), or [PySide](http://www.pyside.org/).